# Problems with sys.path on Python shell

Tags: python, numpy, sys.path

I'm trying to run a Python code that imports Numpy. However, everytime I tried to do it, it shown

```
Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory;
please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there.
```

Then I removed the Numpy directory with

```
sys.path.remove(\...)
```

and to restart the Python shell. Now It still shows the same error message and when I try to use sys.path commands, it prints

```
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

To solve this you need to "import sys" before you call any functions with it.

Answer (score 0):

I find that I must only write `import sys` :)